# Thread: signal SIGABRT (lldb) and program ended with exit code -1

Tags: c, xcode, multithreading, printf, sigabrt

Program stops and the thread appears in the line of sprint:

```
sprintf(x,"%d",x2);
```

Isn't this the best way to turn an int (x2) to a string(x)??

```
int check(int n,char [8]);

int main(){
    char x[8]="0";
     int N,x2;

    scanf("%d",&N);
    while(strlen(x)<9){
        if(check(N,x)) printf("%s\n",x);
        x2=atoi(x);
        x2++;
        sprintf(x,"%d",x2);
        }
    return 0;
    }


int check(int n,char x[8]){
    int l,i,y,count;
    l=strlen(x);
    y=atoi(x);
    count=0;
    for(i=0;i<l;i++){
        count=count+pow((x[i]-'0'),n);
    }
    if(count==y) return 1;
    else return 0; }
```

Comment: `char x[8]="0";` and `while(strlen(x)<9){` ...

x only can hold a string of length 7 plus the null terminator, if you run the loop until it gets to length < 9 you're overflowing it when it reaches length 8 ...

Comment: But even if i had `char x[9]="0"` it would be the same thread and exit -1

Comment: because the loop prints a string of length 9 once before terminating ... does it still crash with `char x[10] = "0"`?

Comment: yep its the same thing! The SIGABRT thread is probably for sprint()

Comment: I'm getting `*** stack smashing detected ***: ./foo terminated` when the program ends, and that is fixed when converting all `char [8]` to `char [10]` ...

Comment: I tried it but nothing! If you run the program and give an ex 3 as input the output numbers are all correct but the program can't finish cause of the thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be more useful if you'd have posted your compile line + code that actually compiled (i.e. had the correct headers included!). With the move to an array size of 10 this works fine (although takes a while to exit!):

The modified code:

```
C:\...>cat main.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

int check(int n,char [10]);

int main(){
    char x[10]="0";
     int N,x2;

    scanf("%d",&N);
    while(strlen(x)<9){
        if(check(N,x)) printf("%s\n",x);
        x2=atoi(x);
        x2++;
        sprintf(x,"%d",x2);
        }
    return 0;
    }


int check(int n,char x[10]){
    int l,i,y,count;
    l=strlen(x);
    y=atoi(x);
    count=0;
    for(i=0;i<l;i++){
        count=count+pow((x[i]-'0'),n);
    }
    if(count==y) return 1;
    else return 0; }
```

Compile and link:

```
C:\...>gcc -Wall -g main.c
```

Debug:

```
C:\...>gdb a.exe
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.6.2
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-w64-mingw32".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
Reading symbols from C:\...\a.exe...done.
(gdb) run
Starting program: C:\.../a.exe
[New Thread 8396.0x199c]
3
0
1
153
370
371
407
[Inferior 1 (process 8396) exited normally]
(gdb) quit
```

All is good with the world! :D

Comment: You're right but it does takes a while for sure so i will try not to use any string and use integers only instead hope it gives a solution to time prob:)